# Ideology of R' S. R. Hirsch

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, samson-raphael-hirsch

Perhaps someone can summarize the idea of "Torah im Derech Eretz" as endorsed by R' Samson Raphael Hirsch.

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12819/torah-im-derech-eretz-and-torah-umada

Answer (score 2):

http://www.stevens.edu/golem/llevine/rsrh/danziger_tide.pdf